# How to get the first file with a .txt extension in a directory with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The directory all my files are in is: '/usr/home/jordan' and I have many files under there (in the directory itself, but one file that is named with a .txt extension.

With nodejs and fs, I want to put that first file (or any file) with a txt extension into "mytxtfilepath". I only have a single .txt file in the whole directory (amongst many other files but with different extensions) The single .txt file could be named ANYTHING, I cannot guarantee what the name will be at any given time, only that it ends in .txt:

```
var homedir = "/usr/home/jordan";
var mytxtfilepath=homedir + "???????";
fs.readfile(mytxtfilepath, function(err,data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

How do I put the correct path to my txt file without hardcoding the name of the txt file itself?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(homedir);
var path = require('path');

for(var i in files) {
   if(path.extname(files[i]) === ".txt") {
       //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple files in the directory, but only one .txt file.

Comment: @dandavis Since when `filter` is faster than loop? Since when regexps are faster than exact comparison? You're wrong.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: path.extname() was userland, which then ran slower than  rx.test(). for has always been faster than filter, i wouldn't argue otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Glob Module](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) as well. It works fine for me!

```
var glob = require( 'glob' );  
var myPath= "/fileFolder/**/*.txt";

glob(myPath, function (er, files) {
    // Files is an array of filenames.
    // Do something with files.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fs.readdir](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) to list the files and find the one that ends with `.txt`:

```
var myPath = "/usr/home/jordan";
fs.readdir(path, function(fileNames) {
    for(var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
      var fileName = fileNames[i];
      if(path.extname(fileName) === ".txt") {
        fs.readfile(path.join(myPath,fileName), function(err,data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Note this requires [path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) so add `var path = require("path")` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fs.readdir](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) and [path.extname](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p)

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path');

function getFileWithExtensionName(dir, ext) {
  fs.readdir(dir, function(files){
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (path.extname(files[i]) === '.' + ext)
        return files[i]
    }
  });
}

var homedir = "/usr/home/jordan";
var mytxtfilepath= getFileWithExtensionName(homedir, 'txt')
fs.readfile(mytxtfilepath, function(err,data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: path must be a string` using this method (after adjusting the above to use `readFile` instead of `readfile`)

Answer (score 0):

The lazy solution:

```
npm install --save readdir
```

and then

```
const {read} = require('readdir');
read("/usr/home/jordan", "**/*.txt", (err, paths) =>
    console.log(paths)
);
```