# How to find all files by extension?

Tags: node.js

I create this code that find for me all files that I have in folders, but I need that code to show me a full name of txt files (only txt) that string I insert there.
For example:
I insert "Alex"
and it searching for all txt files that I have, and if it find it will give me a full name of txt file (example: "redme.txt")

What I need to change in my code?

this my code:
[image: this my code]

Comment: Are you asking people to do the work for you? If so, this is not a place to hire someone, but you may be interested in UpWork and similar sites. If not, please show us what you have attempted and explain the issues you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

the question in the link below may give you the idea

[How to get the first file with a .txt extension in a directory with nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518193/how-to-get-the-first-file-with-a-txt-extension-in-a-directory-with-nodejs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

First, try to get all files in a directory. Then, Sort out the .txt extensions. Next, compare the filename to the given string in the argument.

Comment: thanks! i never used at nodejs before and i not have Experience with this, for begging i must to start  nodejs command prompt, choise location (where i want to do my project), and install "express -e ." and write the code in visual studio?

Comment: If you are starting with Visual Studio, why not trying this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-nodejs

Comment: and u might find this one interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments
It's how u can take the argument from the command line. Hope it helps.